# anaconda3/bin/python: undefined symbol: archive_errno

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Anaconda 4.7.10 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and everything worked smoothly.
After a couple of days I wanted to install "sqlalchemy" but this time I got the error message below. Since then almost every conda command yields the message below. Including`conda update --all` and `conda upgrade`.

Any suggestions?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
        module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .install import install
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 19, in <module>
        from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
        from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 3, in <module>
        from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .entry import ArchiveEntry
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/entry.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import ffi
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 108, in <module>
        errno = ffi('errno', [c_archive_p], c_int)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 95, in ffi
        f = getattr(libarchive, 'archive_'+name)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    AttributeError: /home/martin/anaconda3/bin/python: undefined symbol: archive_errno

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
        return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
        return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
        return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
        return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
        self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1190, in print_unexpected_error_report
        from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
        from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
        from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 7, in <module>
        from .tarball import CondaTarBZ2 as _CondaTarBZ2
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_package_handling/tarball.py", line 7, in <module>
        import libarchive
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .entry import ArchiveEntry
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/entry.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import ffi
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 108, in <module>
        errno = ffi('errno', [c_archive_p], c_int)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 95, in ffi
        f = getattr(libarchive, 'archive_'+name)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    AttributeError: /home/martin/anaconda3/bin/python: undefined symbol: archive_errno
```

Comment: the problem seems to occur when I do `conda update anaconda`or when I install certain libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I've came across the same error on my conda installation in windows subsystem for linux and could solve it by installing libarchive-dev. This seems to be some kind of hidden dependency, libarchive was not installed on my system previously.

```
apt-get install libarchive-dev
```